# Correct abbreviation for “niente”?

Tags: notation, dynamics

“*Niente*” (“nothing”) is used to start a crescendo from silence or end a diminuendo with silence.

Some scores spell it out fully (from “Titanic Suite”, published by Hal Leonard):
[image: Diminuendo from mp to niente]

Other scores abbreviate it as “*n.*” in italic typeface ([“Diagon Alley” score reduction on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrvCQKIdCa8)):
[image: Diminuendo to n.]

Meanwhile, in my scores I’ve always abbreviated it with the bold italic dynamic typeface:
[image: Diminuendo to n]

I did some looking around just now but I couldn’t find any rules, guidelines or other references to which manner of abbreviating it is considered more correct. The few scores I have that abbreviate it use *n.*, but most of those are film scores, which use some specific conventions anyway, so I hesitate to draw conclusions from that.

Is there any reason – logical, historical, etc. – to prefer either *n.* or ***n***, or is it up to personal preference?

Comment: It depends on the publisher: they will all have exact specifications and they will all be different.

Comment: I would prefer >>>> ppp

Comment: There's also a diminishing hairpin with ° at the right-hand point. Sibelius will draw this for you; it's one of the (many) line styles.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli ppp is not the same as niente. You can even start at ppp and decrescendo al niente.

Comment: I always start with niente ;)

Answer (score 5):

The n should be in the same font as the letters used for other dynamic marks, i.e. f, p, m, s, r, and z (s r and z are for dynamic marks like sfz and rf).

In good quality music engraving these will be a font style reserved only for dynamics, and the font only includes the relevant letters - including n.

According to the "bible" of modern notation, Gould's "Behind Bars", the standard abbreviation is a small circle at the end of a hairpin, but the letter n is often used instead.

Comment: Indeed, using a style similar to other dynamic marks is exactly why I’ve gone with the bold-italic ***n*** in the first place. After all this time I was just curious whether I was actually doing it right or not. And personally, I don’t like the hairpins with circles on the ends.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve never encountered this sign! It is really superfluous imho.

The flowing liste in German says:

If the volume at the end of a sliding dynamic change is to be reduced to silence, this is sometimes marked with the letter n at the end of crescendo / decrescendo forks.  The letter n stands for "al niente" (= "to nothing").

https://www.musiktreff.info/lexikon/2-musikalische-fachbegriffe/3326-dynamikbezeichnungen.html