# meaning of the small circle at the end of the decrescendo?

Tags: notation, dynamics

Came across this variety of decrescendo in a vocal piece our choir is working on. 3 in the 13-page piece, all in the space of 3 bars, early in the piece, 2 of which are shown here. My choral director has never seen this before, nor have I. The notes in all 3 cases are followed by rests, so it's not necessary to indicate, say, "decrescendo to silence".
The composer's website used to have a link to ask questions, but she removed that recently, so no way to ask her that I know of. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Could you add the author and the title of the piece?

Comment: This would be _al niente_

Comment: Maybe the singer is supposed to keep their mouth open until they run out of air

Comment: Yes, this is decrescendo to silence or _al niente_. And no, the rest does not make this redundant. The circle basically says that at time you reach the end of the note it should be gone. If it weren’t there one might simply reduce the volume, but not to nothingness.

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, but see other discussion of this phenomenon at [Notation for rapid diminuendo](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/122657/notation-for-rapid-diminuendo)

Comment: Thanks to all. Al niente / fade to nothing makes sense.

Comment: Thanks to all. Al niente / fade to nothing makes sense. The piece is "When the Violin" by Reena Esmail, who is based out of LA. I personally LOVE the piece. We are singing the SATB + cello version this Spring. Here is the best performance video I have found to date:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-U8Y7c1I0ic     Thanks to all for their input!

Answer (score 16):

Al niente. The decrescendo applies to the note length concerned (here a tied crotchet), and as the singer reaches the second beat, the decrescendo should just have finished, down to silence.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or an example of another piece where it is used?  I could imagine that it could mean something else.

Comment: @phoog Gould p.108 "A small circle at the closed end of a hairpin may be used to indicate growing from, as well as fading to, nothing."

Comment: Note the *(n)* below the 3rd line means basically the same thing.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Here, it might be a lyric.

Comment: @Karlo Not likely if it's in parentheses like that.  I suppose it's possible, but we'd have to see more of the score to be sure.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - there's a faint possibility that the (n) actually reminds us of niente.

Comment: In this score, the "(n)" indicates the voicing of the letter n in "when".  Thanks to all, Brian (OP)

Comment: With more of the score available, the question would be more lucid.

Answer (score 1):

The circle indicates *al niente*. Essentially the composer wants you to fade *to nothing* when you decrescendo.

Comment: Isn't that in my earlier answer? What does it add?

Comment: I'm new here lol. I don't quite know the etiquette